# Google Adwords API error - The OAuth client was deleted

Tags: api, google-ads-api

I'm new to the Google Adwords API and so far have managed to get the refresh token by running 'GetRefreshToken.php' via the command line.

/usr/bin/env php mypath/adwords/examples/AdWords/Auth/GetRefreshToken.php

However, when trying out one of the recommended examples - 'GetCampaigns.php', I get the following error -

An error has occurred: {

"error" : "deleted_client",

"error_description" : "The OAuth client was deleted."

}

Has anyone else had this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with the Calendar api. The way to fixed was to delete the files in the .credentials folder in my home directory. Then when i used the new credentials and it worked fine!.

In my case the ./credentials folder was in the following path:

`/Users/myusername/.credentials`

I'm using OS X Yosemite 10.10.5